# How to automatically align the height of the GridView item?

Tags: android, gridview

My activity has 3 elements. Linearlayout, Gridview and the Linearlayout. See picture. How to make Gridview items is completely visible even if there is a scroll on all screens? p.s. Sorry for my English.
[image]

Comment: so you want to fit fixed size grid in screen?

Comment: I want part of the element is not hidden. I want to see them completely in the visible area of the GridView

Comment: Use relative layout

Answer (score 0):

```
 Well use this code for such a layout design...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTopLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/btn_br_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primiumGameNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="Layout1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridViewID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTopLay"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutBottomLay"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutBottomLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/btn_br_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="24"
        android:text="Layout2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way how to do it is to use `layout_weight` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        />
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >
        <!-- put content here -->
    </GridLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```